# PCF app connecting to Spring AMQP - different messaging service after binding app to RabbitMQ service

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange, pcf

I am new to PCF and need some help understanding the root cause of an issue I am facing.

We have one PCF application that is connecting to Rabbit MQ (no binding done on the Rabbit MQ service yet). the messages get passed through the application to queues created on this Rabbit MQ instance. so far so good.

But when we bind again the application to the same Rabbit MQ instance and restage the application, it starts getting connected to a different messaging instance and the message is being relayed to that messaging service and no message transfer happened on expected Rabbit MQ instance although I can't see the actual movement of messages because I might not be having access to the mystery messaging service (I say that because two spring boot services are communicating as expected and the process gets completed).

I am clueless as to what is changing in the application by binding it to Rabbit MQ. is it a default spring implementation of spring AMQP which is interfering here? what can I do to stop this behavior? I haven't provided any parameters while binding the app to Rabbit MQ.

I tried to put the loggers to find out the name of the exchange it's getting connected to but it's still the same exchange, but I can't see the messages flowing and can't explain the phenomenon to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the service key of the your rabbit instance and that will give you hostname etc. i.e. rabbitmq details where you are connecting to after binding.

```
cf service-key SERVICE_INSTANCE SERVICE_KEY
```

Not sure if there is any default setting in the app that's being used for setting up the connection to a different rabbit instance in absence of binding.